# error with git clone

Tags: git, git-clone

I have a strange problem with git. When I try to clone a repository (I tried with severals) the terminal outputs:

```
ma7730@debian:$ git clone https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation.git
Cloning into 'QGIS-Documentation'... 
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation.git/': GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
```

Using **git 2.1.0** on a **debian testing (jessie)** machine.

I don't know what should I do to fix this problem, somebody has an idea?

Comment: It would be useful to see the whole command so that we can see if it is reproducable. If not, we might also need to understand your environment a bit more.

Comment: And the version of git (for information, I'm running 1.9.1 and cloning the URL works).

Comment: thanks guys, I made some edits to the question..

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and bumped into this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-code-hosting/z6PUO8pdB3Q).

As per augie's suggestion, you should try the operation with verbosity activated:

```
ma7730@debian:$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation.git
```

And see what you get. For me, repeating the command with debug activated seemed to solve the problem.